# PHP check if file is in use

Tags: php, file

I want to make a flat files database which will use .php files to store data from the website. My only problem is that if when I 'select' something from the flatfile database (that means the file is read), if in that moment a 'update' is in progress (that means the file is modified and written), the file gets blank and I lose all the content.

I thought about something, to check if the file is in use at the moment, and if it is, to wait a couple of milliseconds and check again.

Comment: I just want to create my own system.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

look into `flock()` http://php.net/manual/en/function.flock.php

Comment: Did this solve your issue? I'm also trying to use this, but it seems like flock doesn't lock the file across different apache requests. So, for instance, if one user locks a file and another user, in another apache request, checks for the lock, the file will not be locked. Seems like flock works only for the current PHP instance. Didn't you face this problem?

Comment: @AlexandreSchmidt Maybe because `flock` uses advisory locks? http://php.net/manual/en/function.flock.php#78318

Comment: Look at the following tutorial, very useful: http://www.hackingwithphp.com/8/11/0/locking-files-with-flock

Answer (score -3):

Please Try this It worked on my case....

```
    if(readyToRead(__FILE__)){
        echo "File is ready to read.";
    } else{
        echo "File is used by somebody else.";
    }

   function readyToRead($file){
       return ((time() - filemtime($file)) > 5 ) ? true : false;
   }
```