# Ajax Php get file from server, how to detect the file is open

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

There is this case.
I have many files(data) in the server. I use `Ajax` and `php` for `Client browser` to get the data from the server.

When a person opens a website and accesses a file from the server, at the same time, if another person(user) open this website, I want to find a way to detect that file is open, if so, I can load a different file or just block this user.

How can I do this, any suggestion is appreciated, thanks for your time!

Ajax get the file

```
load: function (url) {
        var _this = this;
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: url,
            dataType: "text",
            success: function (json) {
                if (typeof json == 'string' || json instanceof String) {
                    json = JSON.parse(json);
                    _this.parse(json);
                }
            }
        });
    },
```

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6341196/php-check-if-file-is-in-use

Comment: @ Siva.G No, this is different. Actually I use ajax get the file. How to use flock? He is open the file in php, and the staus is control in php.

Comment: @yongnan php actually does not care / have no way of knowing wether a call is ajax or normal; they are both http request and will be treated the same way. hence it pretty much is a duplicate :)

Comment: There is a common non standard way of identifying ajax requests. Many JavaScript ajax libraries set an http header: `X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest`. There is no international standard for this, but it seems to be a well used convention.

Comment: Thanks, Sorry, I am wrong. Maybe I do not explain my question very clearly. So if I use the flock. when a person open the website, he get the data from `php`, The `php` which has an exclusive lock, and a release lock. So After the data is loaded the lock is release? So when another person coming, he can also Open the file, Right? Because when finishing loading the data, the lock is released.

Comment: I think there is a way to solve this, when a person open the website, he assess one file from php(ajax), and in another directory he create a tmp file, when he finished (after clicking), I delete those tmp file. So Another person coming, he can check if the same name tmp file exists, if so, he could not open it. and get another file.(create a tmp file). Maybe this is not a good way, because I have many files in a directory, so I will create a lot of files. I just want to say this is not a duplicate question.

Comment: Finally, I solve this problem, please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24961559/ajax-php-file-control

Answer (score 1):

You can use global variables:

```
<?php
if($_GLOBAL["locked"]) {
     header("HTTP/1.0 503 Service Unavailable");
     exit(0);
} else {
     $_GLOBAL["locked"]=true;
     //send file
     $_GLOBAL["locked"]=false;
     exit(0);
}
?>
```

The variable 'locked' will persist throughout all of the php files.

Comment: thanks, I still do not know how to solve the problem. because after sending the file the lock is released, so another person can assess. it. Actually, The first person can write the data back after click a button(using ajax and php), at this time he can release the lock. Is it possible? Another thing is I want to lock the certain file, If a new person coming, I can give him another file, if he find the file is in using.